# Solving for x with radicals and negative exponents

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

How do I go about solving for $x$ in this equation?

$$\displaystyle -x^{-\large\frac{3}{4}} + \frac{15^{\large\frac{1}{4}}}{15} = 0$$

Comment: I've edited for formatting --- please check to see that I got it right.

Comment: You had it right @Gerry. Then it was edited after your edit using teeny-tiny fractional exponents. So I made them larger.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$-x^{-3/4} + \frac{15^{1/4}}{15} = 0 \iff -\frac {1}{x^{3/4}} + \frac{15^{1/4}}{15^{4/4}} = 0$$

$$\iff -\frac {1}{x^{3/4}} + \frac{1}{15^{3/4}}  = 0$$

$$\iff \dfrac{x^{3/4}}{15^{3/4}} = 1 \iff \left(\frac{x}{15}\right)^{3/4} = 1$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: its 15! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, your correct!  You're welcome!